# How do I handle multiple correct, yet distinctly different answers?

Tags: discussion

I recently [asked a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45179/how-can-i-write-windowing-query-which-sums-a-column-to-create-discrete-buckets) that has multiple correct answers, each with their own pros and cons.  Nick's answer uses recursive CTE's to provide the solution as efficiently as possible, but Sebastian's is much easier to implement, debug, and make changes to (very important in my work environment).  Since neither is technically wrong, how should I decide which is "most right" when it comes to formally accepting the answer?

Comment: Some related discussion on the main meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users and also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Those answered my question, I guess I didn't phrase my initial search correctly to find them.  Thank you.

Comment: well, it is a different meta site, after all, so no fault there. :-)

Answer (score 10):

Pick the answer that you used.

This is expanded on here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

as "Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally"

Comment: Link please? Thanks

Comment: I know what you meant, what am I asking for is a link showing that what you indicate is how I should have posted. e.g. some kind of guidance document, as I do not believe you to be correct at the moment but am willing to be taught that I am wrong, if it's more than merely your opinion.

Comment: It's my opinion those links do not support your position. It did lead me to edit my Answer however.

Comment: Oh ok. I get now what you are trying to say. It depends on where you place emphasis when you read your answer. You are telling Zikes that he should select the answer that works for him (in answer to his question). I understood you to be commenting on his question and telling him to post whatever he did to resolve his question. Gotcha. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Pick the answer that will be most useful to future visitors. Most questions have dozens of interested visitors with the same question. The asker is just one of them.

Comment: 1. How can the poser  of the question know this? 2. The question that is most useful  for future visitors is probably the question that gets the most upvotes.

Comment: @miracle173 1. Are you saying there is no way of predicting what solution will apply to the most number of teams? Well, if that's impossible I guess mark the answer that you used. 2. Might well be true, but I don't get the point relating to this answer. Please explain.

Comment: 1. How should a user predict the usefulness of an answer? And why "the most number of teams"? Shouldn't this be  the most number of readers of the question?  2. I think a large number of upvotes shows that a  large number of visitors find this answer useful in the past. Therefore I would expect that  a large number of visitors will find the answer useful in the future, too.

Comment: Yeah, equating teams and readers here. Try to think with me and understand what I mean instead of picking the one possible meaning that works against my argument.; Example: My specific case might be solved by fixing some niche mistake I made but someone writes a really complete tutorial style answer that addresses all kinds of more common issues. This is very common with programming topics (DBA often involving programming in some form). I see you are more of a math guy on SE so maybe it's different there. @miracle173