# Floating dialogs get clipped and appear way off-center

Tags: bug, css, vote-to-close

When I vote to close one of my own questions here on dba.SE meta, or on dba.SE, the dialog is off-center and clipped. This does not happen on our main site or on any other site in the network as far as I can tell. I also believe this is a new symptom since the roll-out of close vote changes.

[image]

To reproduce, simply vote to close a question you asked. Though it seems to be browser-specific. I am running Chrome 27.0.1453.116 on Mac OS 10.9 and the symptom does not happen on Safari.

Also, it seems to be question-specific, and, in fact, asker-specific. It happens on this question and on [this question also](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/988/a-request-for-elaboration-when-migrating-so-questions), both asked by me, but not any questions not asked by me, e.g. [this question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/989/how-do-i-handle-multiple-correct-yet-distinctly-different-answers).

On the plus side, it's easy enough to grab the floating window and drag it to somewhere useful.

Now, how often are we voting to close our own questions? Pretty seldom. But the same thing happens for the mod dialog, which may be more common (e.g. purging comments):

[image]

*Whoa, inception. Kind of.*

Comment: I can't repro this on Chrome 27, OSX 10.7(Lion). Are you on Mavericks Beta?

Comment: @Jin yes. Now, was it a question *you* asked? That seems to be one of the deciding factors.

Comment: @Jin also, I am now finding this is network-wide for me. It's just less severe on other sites because they don't clip there (different z-index of the edges I suppose).

Comment: I couldn't repro when I tried to close my own question on our dev server(which has the exact same css as live). Can you repro this on another Mac that's not running Mavericks Beta?

Comment: @Jin no, doesn't repro on 10.8.2, so I guess it's a Mavericks beta thing. Still, is there some difference in any of the CSS or what gets inherited by those dialogs when the question is my own vs. someone else's? Trying to think why any destructive artifacts would affect such an isolated part of the site.

Comment: That's very odd indeed. I've never seen a css bug due to an OS... From your screenshot, it looks like the modal has no z-index, therefore being contained in #content div.

Comment: @Jin maybe I'll file a bug on the main meta if this issue persists beyond the next Mavericks refresh. Due in the fall I don't think it's something you need to worry about yet, especially if it's isolated to this build. When I first filed the bug report I hadn't ruled out a lot of the limiting factors that I have since...

Comment: @Jin [this one also seems OS-specific](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/993/action-line-spreads-across-two-lines-when-too-much-going-on).